# Getting error in DispatcherServlet during startup

Tags: java

Does anyone see conflicting jars here that might cause exception during tomcat startup. Below is the exception. I updated the maven dependencies in the project properties.

Error

```
SEVERE: Servlet /TransactionRetrieval threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)


junit-3.8.1.jar
spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar
spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar
commons-logging-1.2.jar
spring-expression-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar
servlet-api-2.5.jar
jstl-1.2.jar
jackson-databind/2.5.3/jackson-databind-2.5.3.jar
jackson-annotations/2.5.0/jackson-annotations-2.5.0.jar
jackson-core/2.5.3/jackson-core-2.5.3.jar
jersey-server-1.8.jar
/Users/vamsikrishna/.m2/repository/asm/asm/3.1/asm-3.1.jar
jersey-core-1.8.jar
jersey-json-1.8.jar
jettison-1.1.jar
stax-api-1.0.1.jar
jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar
jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar
stax-api-1.0-2.jar
activation-1.1.jar
jackson-core-asl-1.7.1.jar
jackson-mapper-asl-1.7.1.jar
jackson-jaxrs-1.7.1.jar
jackson-xc-1.7.1.jar
```

Comment: Which version of tomcat are you using? And is it possible for you to try version 3.0 of servlet-API? Also, check your classpath.

Comment: using tomcat 7. When I try 3.0 I get the error Missing artifact javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:3.0

Comment: Also, I keep getting this ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception

Comment: Sep 12, 2017 8:15:41 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.WebAppResourceConfig init
INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the Web app resource paths:
  /WEB-INF/lib
  /WEB-INF/classes
Sep 12, 2017 8:15:42 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 27745
 at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readClass(Unknown Source)
 at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
 at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)

Comment: I don't understand that list of jar files. Why do some of them have paths? They are all supposed to be in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder, and hence should not have any paths other than that, inside the war file you deployed to Tomcat. Are all those jar files in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder? If not, then there is your answer, because `DispatcherServlet` is in the `spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar` file.

Comment: Also, don't post code and/or log lines in comments. Edit the question to clarify it.

Comment: they are in maven dependencies folder